# Search Lucene with precise edit distances

Tags: lucene, fuzzy-search

I would like to search a Lucene index with edit distances. For example, say, there is a document with a field FIRST_NAME; I want all documents with first names that are 1 edit distance away from, say, 'john'.

I know that Lucene supports fuzzy searches (FIRST_NAME:john~) and takes a number between 0 and 1 to control the fuzziness. The problem (for me) is this number does not directly translate to an edit distance. And when the values in the documents are short strings (less than 3 characters) the fuzzy search has difficulty finding them. For example if there is a document with FIRST_NAME 'J' and I search for FIRST_NAME:I~0.0 I don't get anything back.

Answer (score 4):

In Lucene's FuzzyQuery, you cannot specify the extact distance. You can specify the value of "fuzziness" between 0 and 1 where values closer to 0 indicate broad match and values closer to 1 indicate narrow match. The formula for "fuzziness" is as follows. (From Lucene in Action)

[image]

From this formula, you can work back to an approximate fuzziness for given value of distance. So, `StackOverflow` is to be matched with `StackUnderflow`, which is at a distance of 3, the fuzziness required will be approximately 0.77.

Comment: Looking in Lucene in Action the formula they have on page 93 is `1 - distance / min(textlen, targetlen)`, but this cannot be fully correct because it allows for values that are less than 0.0. In my testing the formula does in fact use `min(textlen, targetlen)` (unlike their implementation of LevensteinDistance, which uses `1 - distance / max(textlen, targetlen)`) so they must make it impossible to return strings that require more changes than the length of the shorter string.

Answer (score 2):

If you only need 1 edit distance away and if the result can contain the exact match, then you can use the single character wildcard in the query language. If the name is

```
john
```

then the query that matches it and any term within 1 edit distance would look like

```
?john OR j?ohn OR jo?hn OR joh?n OR john? OR ohn OR jhn OR joh OR ?ohn OR j?hn OR jo?n OR joh?
```

For more more complex cases, you might need to get a list of terms in the index (using [IndexReader.term()](http://lucene.apache.org/java/3_0_0/api/all/org/apache/lucene/index/IndexReader.html#terms%28%29)), keep the ones that are 1 edit distance away, and search for any of those terms.